# How to check the role of an authenticated user in a Jersey web service

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, jersey, jax-rs

**Environment**: Jersey 1.17 with GlassFish 3.1.2.2, JDK 6u31.

**web.xml** security segment:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>SSL transport</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure Area</web-resource-name>
        <description></description>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description></description>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

**sun-web.xml**:

```xml
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
    <group-name>USER</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    <group-name>ADMIN</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

I am using injection to get hold of the [`SecurityContext`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.17/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html) instance:

```java
@Context
private SecurityContext sec;
```

Now I should be able to check roles inside web service methods with the [`SecurityContext#isUserInRole(String role)`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.17/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29) method, however no matter what is specified as parameter, the returned value is always `false`.

I am able to retrieve the authenticated user's name with the [`SecurityContext#getUserPrincipal()`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.17/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29) method.

What could be the problem here? Is there an other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to specify the security roles in `web.xml` separately too:

```xml
<!-- after <login-config /> -->
<security-role>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>
```